# Installing Windows 10 on External Drive

Tags: windows-10, installation, external-drive

This question has been asked a few times and all had good replies that I have followed and it seems I am SO close to getting this done... But the Windows 10 ISO I have downloaded from Microsoft does not have a "Install.WIM" file on it! (A windows 7 ISO I have does have that file, but I wanted Win10 on this external)

The only .WIM file I can find on it is Boot.WIM
Will that file suffice or is there another file I should be copying to the external drive to make it work? For example, there is a file called Install.ECM in the \sources\ folder.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did a test and YES, the Boot.WIM file works and using GImageX works fine to install the required files for windows.

However... I then try to run BCDBoot.exe from that external drive and I come up with an error:

The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-heap-I2-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I am trying to make a Windows 10 external drive, from a machine that is currently running Windows 7. Does that make a difference? Any other reasons why that file isn't present? Could it be that Boot.WIM doesn't have that file and should?

Comment: OK, the answer to that second question is: Yes, you have to run BCDBoot.exe from a Windows 10 machine, to make the external drive bootable, if you want Windows 10 to work.

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You used the Media Creation tool and this includes ESD files. You can [convert the ESD into a WIM](https://github.com/gus33000/ESD-Decrypter) or [download proper ISOs from this Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/techbench) which includes an `install.wim`.